# Why is my django file submission not posting?

Tags: python, django, forms, post, upload

I am busy building a conference website application where is is necessary to be able to upload articles. These articles should also be able to assigned to reviewers to get downloaded and scored. My problem comes with the uploading of the files. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I think my form is submitting the incorrect data since it doesn't run through the 'if `form.is_valid:`' part. I am still a beginner at this. I have watched multiple tutorials.

This is what my model.py file looks like:

```
from django.db import models
from time import time

def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    abstract = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date published')
    ffile = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.title)
```

This is my admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Article

admin.site.register(Article)
```

This is my forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Article

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('title','abstract','pub_date','ffile')
```

This is my views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import ArticleForm

def upload_article(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = ArticleForm(file_field=request.FILES[''])
            form.save()
            instance.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/articles/')

    else: 
        form = ArticleForm()

    return render_to_response('submit/form.html', {'form' : form})
```

And then my HTML template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <form method="post" action="../upload/" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}

        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

There is no problems with my urls.. Can someone please help me. Or at least suggest a third party app that might make this easier?

I can post normal forms that is not uploading files, but I just can't seem to get this one.

Comment: why are you using this "instance = ArticleForm(file_field=request.FILES['']) "?

Comment: Are you saying your form is never valid? If not then you could print `form.errors` and see what caused the error.

Comment: thank you, I will try that. I am not sure anymore why Im using instance..

Comment: I tried `forms.errors` and it displayed that the file field that uploads the file is required. What does that means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution to the posting problem.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from time import time

# Function to determine where to place uploaded documents 
# Taken from youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b43JIn-OGZU&index=15&list=PLxxA5z-8B2xk4szCgFmgonNcCboyNneMD

def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    # return a string: folder_name/time-of-upload + seperated by underscore + filename
    # Example: media_files/15-10-2015_Submission1
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)

class Document(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField( blank=False, null=True) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.title

class DocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ['title', 'file']
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Document

class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)

    file = forms.FileField(
        label = 'Select a file',
        help_text = 'maximum file size: 50mb',
        allow_empty_file=False
    )
```

views.py

```
#@login_required
def upload_file(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.POST:
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        #print(request.POST['title'], '   ', request.POST['file'])        
       # print(request.FILES['file'])        
        if form.is_valid():
            #newdoc = Document(title = request.FILES['title'])
            form.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('submissions.views.upload_file'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  #A empty, unbound form

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('submissions/submission.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

So one of the problems was that I had to create a `FileField` in the model as weel as in the form.